# Rename files with spaces to underscore in all subcategories

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, command

I have category /products/ and subcategories. I need a one line command to remove spaces from name to underscore and if its 2 spaces put only 1 underscore. Rename command doesn't work on this server.
I've been using `for file in *; do mv "$file" echo $file | tr ' ' '_' ; done` but it doesn't work for subcategories what i have a lot, plus if there is 2 spaces this command gonna make 2 underscores and I need different.
Please advise

Comment: Are spaces present in the product names or subcategories also, or only the file names? Please, show a sample of the hierarchy.

Comment: Your command will make a single underscore from two spaces in the original filename. It would have to be `echo "$file"` to keep all the spaces.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223182/how-to-replace-spaces-in-all-file-names-with-underscore-in-linux-using-shell-scr/223185#223185

Comment: @choroba spaces needs to be changed only in product names.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, seems like I figure out how to make it with this answer

Comment: You probably missed a semicolon somewhere.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, I just need it to put in two lines

Comment: @Barmar the only question now how to change two underscores to one with this command

Comment: Use the rename command. It takes perl regular expressions, and you can use \s+ to match any sequence of spaces.

Comment: @Barmar command rename doesn't work on this server and I'm super bad with regular expressions that's why im asking maybe I can change the command `find $1 -name "* *.xml" -type f -print0 | \
  while read -d $'\0' f; do mv -v "$f" "${f// /_}"; done`  to be able to find __ and change it to _

Comment: You mean `__` in the original name, or `__` after it has replaced the spaces with `_`?

Comment: You'll need to do it in two steps: `newf=${f// / }` to replace space with underscore, then `newf=${newf//__/_}` to replace two underscores with one underscore, then `mv -v "$f" "$newf"`

Comment: @Barmar yes After I used command `find $1 -name "* *.xml" -type f -print0 | \ while read -d $'\0' f; do mv -v "$f" "${f// /_}"; done` I got two underscores in names and now I need to change it to one. So I was trying to use `find $1 -name "* *.xml" -type f -print0 | \ while read -d $'\0' f; do mv -v "$f" "${f//__ /_}"; done` but it didn't work

Comment: You have a space after the two underscores in `${f//__ /_}`

Comment: Also, you need to change the `find` command to look for `*__*.xml` instead of `* *.xml`. Do you understand what the commands are doing, or are you just blindly copying things and making random changes to them?

Comment: @Barmar i'm sorry, of course i'm not an expert but still this `find $1 -name "*__*.jpg" -type f -print0 | \
  while read -d $'\0' f; do mv -v "$f" "${f//__  /_}"; done ` doesn't work, Im getting mv: `./grade_6_591__593.5__594.5__595__597_597l_598_602h_602eh_602eh.5_qualitative_filter_papers_33.jpg' and `./grade_6_591__593.5__594.5__595__597_597l_598_602h_602eh_602eh.5_qualitative_filter_papers_33.jpg' are the same file

Comment: You still have a space after `__` in `"${f//__ /_}"` But the filenames son't have a space there, so there's nothing for it to match.

Comment: @Barmar thank you a lot, it worked, you should make this as an answer so people will know what to do, im sure im not alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Barmar. I used command from answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223182/how-to-replace-spaces-in-all-file-names-with-underscore-in-linux-using-shell-scr/223185#223185

Just make sure its in two lines

Answer (score 1):

## Update:

OP found (as noted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40227451/3544399) a more reliable way to strip spaces from files, which he notes here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/223185 :

> find -name "* *" -print0 | sort -rz | \   while read -d $'\0' f; do mv
> -v "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/$(basename "${f// /_}")"; done

---

**Original Answer** (may help someone else as a framework for renaming files if using `bash` and compatible version of *GNU* `sed`

Can you use `find` and `sed` ?

**Edit:**

As a one liner:

```
find "$(pwd)" -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' file ; do newfile="$(echo "$file" | sed -E 's/\s+/_/g')" ; newcmd='mv -v "'"$file"'" "'"$newfile"'"' ; echo "$newcmd" ; done
```

---

```
find "$(pwd)" -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' file
do 
newfile="$(echo "$file" | sed -E 's/\s+/_/g')"
newcmd='mv -v "'"$file"'" "'"$newfile"'"'

#for test run use echo
echo "$newcmd"

#for real run use eval
eval "$newcmd"

done
```

I've found that general style of doing search and replace in file names reliable.  There's a few reasons I don't just use substitution and I don't remember them off the top of my head, but the key points here are;

- You aren't at the mercy of the `$IFS` variable
- Very strange filenames will be enclosed in quotes and suitable for execution
- You're not performing `mv` command directly on glob expansions
- The `\s+` in `sed` will replace **one or more** spaces, as you require

Comment: `Be sure to include the word ``sed'' somewhere in the ``Subject:'' field.
mv -v "/home/dscfilte/public_html/media/catalog/product/2/1/21zh1cb55rl._sx342__1_13.jpg" ""
sed: invalid option -- E
Usage: sed [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]...

  -n, --quiet, --silent
                 suppress automatic printing of pattern space
  -e script, --expression=script
                 add the script to the commands to be executed
  -f script-file, --file=script-file
                 add the contents of script-file to the commands to be executed
`

Comment: `  -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
                 edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
  -c, --copy
                 use copy instead of rename when shuffling files in -i mode
   (avoids change of input file ownership)
  -l N, --line-length=N
                 specify the desired line-wrap length for the `l' command
  --posix
                 disable all GNU extensions.
  `

Comment: `-r, --regexp-extended
                 use extended regular expressions in the script.
  -s, --separate
                 consider files as separate rather than as a single continuous
                 long stream.
  -u, --unbuffered
                 load minimal amounts of data from the input files and flush
                 the output buffers more often
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit`

Comment: `If no -e, --expression, -f, or --file option is given, then the first
non-option argument is taken as the sed script to interpret.  All
remaining arguments are names of input files; if no input files are
specified, then the standard input is read.

E-mail bug reports to: bonzini@gnu.org .`